# React + D3: Rendering a bar chart from data in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm having difficulty rendering a bar chart with d3 (v4) and react.

I'm getting this error

> data.map is not a function

**data is stored in an array formatted as such:**

```
{
Number:["2", "4", "8"]
Species:["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
}
```

**Which is passed into BarChart component as a prop:**

```
 <BarChart data={data} />
```

**BarChart.jsx**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { scaleBand, scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';

class BarChart extends Component {

    render() {

      const svgWidth = 960, svgHeight = 500;

      const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
          width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const data = this.props.data;

      const x = scaleBand.domain(data.map(d => d.Species))
                         .rangeRound([0, width])
                         .padding(0.1),

            y = scaleLinear.domain([0, max(data, d => d.Number)])
                           .rangeRound([height, 0]);

      <svg width={svgWidth} height={svgHeight}>
        <g transform={`translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`}>
          {data.map(d => (
            <rect
              x={x(d.Species)}
              y={y(d.Number)}
              width={x.bandwidth()}
              height={height - y(d.frequency)}
            />
          ))}
        </g>
      </svg>
    }
};


export default BarChart;
```

EDIT:

If I change the format of the object to :

```
data = [
  {
    Number: '2',
    Species: 'Cat'
  },
  {
    Number: '4',
    Species: 'Dog'
  },
  {
    Number: '8',
    Species: 'Rabbit'
  }];
```

I get this error:

> _d3Scale.scaleBand.domain is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data seems to be an object and not an array. for the code to work, data should be:

```
data = [
  {
    Number: '2',
    Species: 'Cat'
  },
  {
    Number: '4',
    Species: 'Dog'
  },
  {
    Number: '8',
    Species: 'Rabbit'
  }];
```

Comment: `data = d3.range( ... );` might be another option.

Comment: @ vijayst, thanks that makes sense, but now i am getting this error: _d3Scale.scaleBand.domain is not a function

Comment: It is scaleBand().domain()